# How to compile with Mono from the command line?

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I've installed monodevelop to give it a try.
I'm able to compile hello-worlds and run it with the monodevelop's GUI, but I would like to also make the equivalent from the command line.

Could someone tell me what is the command line to compile the .cs files?

https://gist.github.com/fccm/cc196a2816b66b66463e425cf1e62adb

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `csc` as it is the replacement for `msc` :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe

Comment: Is it available on Linux?

Comment: Windows, macOS, Linux

Comment: The project file (.csproj) is a MSBuild script, so simply learn and use MSBuild command line.

Comment: Is "MSBuild" available on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, msbuild is available on Linux for a while. Build your project with:
`msbuild helloworld.csproj`

Execute with:
`mono helloworld.exe`